# How to design and implement a wiki?

Tags: java, database-design, wiki

I want to implement a simple wiki. Most probably will be using Java on Google app engine. I have been searching around for sample design or how others have implemented it, what issues they faced, how they solved it etc. But most search queries turned out to be useless as Google gave links to wikis discussing about programming instead of programming sites that discuss about wikis. Can anyone here direct me?

I found this link: http://everything2.com/?node_id=1683000 but honestly couldn't make head or tail out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a discussion about Wiki design here (on this site):

[Designing a Wiki, design considerations and feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273460/)

Answer (score 2):

Do you actually NEED to design your own wiki?  Mediawiki is quite good and should have everything you need.  Plus the installation instructions will get you running in 10-15 minutes.

Don't mean to question your motives, but if it's good enough for Wikipedia it's quite possibly good enough for you.

Comment: Don't Reinvent The Wheel, Unless You Plan on Learning More About Wheels => http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001145.html

Comment: Wiki is a very small part of the application I am designing. Taking a full fledged wiki like MediaWiki and customizing it is gonna take more time that actually completing the app from scratch. Hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [list of open source wikis written in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/wiki-engines) - and [here's another](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?JavaWikiEngines).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs it may be easier to customize one of the solutions available. For this task I found very useful checking [wikimatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/).