# Wiki engine development guideline

Tags: database-design, design-patterns, wiki, instructions

I am not looking for an open source wiki engine. There are plenty of them of course. But is there a guideline or a book on development of a wiki engine from scratch. I'm interested in the methodologies, design patterns, algorithms and best practices used in the area. The more pedagogic it is the better. I'd prefer if that would be in C#.

Answer (score 0):

You probably found you ansnwer by now, but in case somebody else arrives here, one should check [Designing a Wiki, design considerations and feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273460/designing-a-wiki-design-considerations-and-feedback)
which gives good starting principles...